# Currency converter using Polymorphism c#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Is it possible to  make a currency converter object-oriented, using Polymorphism?

```
 public class Product
    {
        public string name;
        public double price;
        public double quantity;

        public Product(string name, double price, int quantity)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Price = price;
            this.Quantity = quantity;
        }

        ...

        public double Price
        {
            get { return this.price; }
            set { this.price = value; }
        }

        ...
```

I have a class Product with paramethers in it that are set for every product in the program. I want to get the Prices and to convert them in other currencies. Is there any way to do that with polymorphism?

Answer (score 0):

Well I could imagine you could have a set of classes like `EUR`, `USD` which would inherit from `Currency`, but each class should have a method to convert *from* any possible currency.

Something like this but for each supported currency.

```
public class EUR : Currency
{
   public override decimal ToEUR(decimal amount)
   {
      return amount;
   }

   public override decimal ToUSD(decimal amount)
   {
      return amount * [ratio to convert from EUR to USD];
   }

   // and the rest of the methods here.
}
```

And Currency would look like this:

```
public class Currency
{
   public virtual decimal ToEUR(decimal amount)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public virtual decimal ToUSD(decimal amount)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   // and the rest of the methods here.
}
```

I'm not sure it's the best approach though, but of course it depends on your scenario.